# "identifier is undefined" when calling function from a header file

Tags: c++

All I'm trying to do is create a separate class to hold my Hello World function (this is for a class), but I am getting an "identifier is undefined" compiler error. What is the issue?

Here is my main function (helloworld.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    print_me();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the header class (helloworld.h) :

```
#include <iostream>

void print_me() {
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
}
```

Comment: Try including the same namespace in your class file ...

Comment: The error still persists, so I do not think that is the issue

Comment: did you #include helloworld.h file in helloworld.cpp?

Comment: Firstly, why do you call it a "class"? There no classes in your code. Secondly, you defined a function in a header file. This is generally incorrect. Why did you decide to place the definition of `print_me` in a header file?

Comment: I'm following along with an online class, and I tried to do what it described. This includes putting the print_me in the header file.

Answer (score 2):

You have not included `helloworld.h` in `helloworld.cpp`. The following code should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "helloworld.h" 

using namespace std;

int main() {
     print_me();
     system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

One thing to remember is from your compiler's point of view,  there is no connection between the two files unless you specify it. The fact that both files have the same name does not have any significance for compiler.

**Side note 1**: Consider using include guards in your header files. For simple projects, it may not be obviously necessary but for larger projects, not using them can lead to annoying ambiguous compilation errors.

**Side note 2**: Implementing function bodies in header files is generally discouraged.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm now getting a "cannot open source file "helloworld.h". Should my header file be in the Source File folder or the Header File folder (where it currently is)?

Comment: That is a different question and it is better to ask it in a different post because this problem may have different causes. However, are you putting the two files in the same directory and invoking compiler from within that directory? Try using full path of header file in the include statement, something like `#include "/path/to/helloworld.h"`.

Comment: I have no idea what the issue was, but if I autocomplete "helloword.h", it works, even though the actual include statement is identical. Thanks for all the help! It complies now.